# Why can't I use the top row of numbers on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that formats my inputs to include decimals.  It seems I can only use my numpad to type numbers in with this script.  How can I make it so the numbers can be typed with the number pad or the number row at the top of the keyboard? and be formatted

```
$('input[name=PercentRate]').on('keydown',function(e){    
    // tab, esc, enter
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [9, 27, 13]) !== -1 ||
        // Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
        // home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    // backspace & del
    if($.inArray(e.keyCode,[8,46]) !== -1){
        $(this).val('');
        return;
    }

    var a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","`"];
    var n = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];

    var value = $(this).val();
    var clean = value.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/,/g,'').replace(/^0+/, '');   

    var charCode = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var p = $.inArray(charCode,a);

    if(p !== -1)
    {
        value = clean + n[p];

        if(value.length == 2) value = '0' + value;
        if(value.length == 1) value = '00' + value;

        var formatted = '';
        for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++)
        {
            var sep = '';
            if(i == 2) sep = '.';
            if(i > 3 && (i+1) % 3 == 0) sep = ',';
            formatted = value.substring(value.length-1-i,value.length-i) + sep + formatted;
        }

        $(this).val(formatted);
    }    

    return;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use console.log to output of the key events of the numbers at the top of the keyboard and determine their numeric values. From there you can add the e.keyCode inclusion logic to your script.

```
$('input[name=PercentRate]').on('keydown',function(e){
   //test out the key codes when you press the top and log
   console.log( e.keyCode );
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with what you have right now.

1. You're only checking in array `a` and not `n` for values. `a` only has letters while `n` has numbers. This creates a coincidence which I'll come back to after.
2. `String.fromCharCode(97)` (97 is the keyCode for Numpad1, notice I said **keyCode** rather than **charCode**) actually returns the character "a".

Here's where the coincidence comes in. Your code doesn't actually work with Numpad1. It just so happens that Numpad1 turns into "a" which gives you the first element in array `a` which makes it look like it's working since "a" is the first element in the `a` array, the same index that 1 has in `n`. In reality, your code thinks you're pressing the "a" key and it only "works" because you made a different mistake elsewhere. You can see this when you change it form `$.inArray(charCode, a)` to `$.inArray(charCode, n)` and top row 1 starts working while Numpad1 doesn't.

This shows us yet another problem that we've come across. `e.keyCode` doesn't actually give you the `charCode`, which is what we want for `String.fromCharCode()`. What you need is the `keypress` event rather than `keydown`, which has the `charCode` field, giving you the correct value of the key pressed using `e.charCode`.

Additionally, you'd have to either make changes to your current code to determine if you should be checking in array `a` or `n`, or merge the two and change your other code to work around the changed index returned. Currently, you're only checking for letters while ignoring all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The character codes for the top row of numbers are different than the number pad numbers.  The character codes for the top row are the actual numbers instead of alternate letter codes.

You just need to make sure that code sent is in one of your two maps.

```
var p = $.inArray(charCode,a);
if(p === -1) p = $.inArray(charCode, n);
```

Should be the only change needed.